# Proof of "$G$ is locally finite and connected" $\iff||G||$ is homeomorphic to $|G|$

Tags: graph-theory

I have trouble understanding the proof of "$G$ is locally finite and connected" $\iff||G||$ is homeomorphic to $|G|.$

The proof is at Theorem 8.8.2 at [Diestel](https://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/home/diestel/books/graph.theory/preview/Ch8.pdf).

At third paragraph of the proof, he consider the case when $x_p$ is a dummy vertex for every $p$.

Would this happen even if $p$ is a partition which send every vertex to singleton which means no dummy vertex?

Update: I'm sorry. I misunderstood the definition of $p$. He only consider the partition which have "finitely" many cross edges. So, partition which send every vertex to singleton is impossible if there is infinite edges.

Comment: Do you still have a question regarding the proof after your update?

Comment: No. I'm now ok with this question